# obj-c nib loaded doesn't follow constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have one view controller : MainViewController

inside the mainViewController, i add a uiview and set all the constraints (0,0,0,0) which means it is same size with the super view.

from the added uiview above, i set the custom class to my UIView file, lets called it xMainView

here is my xMainView code

```
//xMainView.h
@interface xMainView : UIView
// all my properties here
@end

//xMainView.m
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:aRect])) {
    [self commonInit];
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
    [self commonInit];
}
return self;
}

- (void)commonInit{ 
UIView *mapView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XMapView"
                                                 owner:self
                                               options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

mapView.frame = self.bounds;
mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self addSubview: mapView];
}

- (void) loadMap:(NSArray *)results {
self.passedResults = results;

[self commonInit];
[self updateUserCurrentLocation];
[self zoomingToDevice];
}
```

in the xMapView.xib (storyboard) I add another ui view which is set to the bottom of the view. I put the constraint of this view as follow :

```
trailing : 0
bottom : 0
leading : 0
height : 300
```

in my MainViewController, this is how I call my xMainView

```
//the mapStoreView is the view from the MainViewController. I outlet it and name it as mapStoreView
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.mapStoreView loadMap:nil];
}
// I have tried to put it in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, same results
```

[image: Iphone 7+]
[image: Iphone 5]

However, the view from the xMapView seems go bottom off the screen. I already put all the constraint well. The weirdest part is, it runs okay using iphone 7plus. other device, will have the bottom offset screen problem.

I have been looking for hints quite a while and cant find any. it really frustates me. Maybe someone know what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: Try to implement awakeFromNib method in xMainView and call commonInit in it.

Comment: I couldn't understand the loadmap() method if my understanding is correct you have missed something in commonInit() method. try this `[self  addSubView: mapView]`.

Comment: @FebinFathah i have the code at the first place, but i forgot to paste it here

Comment: Still it is not working? Please share a screen shot of your xib

Comment: I have done a demo project to show a custom view for any warning. [Warning- Alert](https://github.com/febinfathah/Warning-Alert) Refer to this if it helps you